# ranking dataframe by multiple columns and assigning the ranks

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im trying to rank values in all the columns one by one and assign the ranks to the values from the first column['Tickers']
and preferably store those ranks in new dataframe
So lets say I have this dataframe:

```
    Ticker  P/E     P/S     P/B     P/FCF      Dividend
No.                     
1   GWRE    433.03  10.15   5.54    47.25       0.0000
2   NTCT    419.51  2.83    1.32    24.30       0.0000
3   PEGA    136.61  4.77    10.43   308.60      0.0026
4   BLKB    90.62   5.14    14.84   43.35       0.0060
5   IRM     80.69   2.66    4.89    100000.00   0.0624
```

so then I would rank by P/E (lowest value gets rank 1), then place the result number in new dataframe

Then go again for the rest of the columns and finally new dataframe would look like this (all ranked the same with exception of the dividend column where highest value gets rank 1):

```
 Ticker   P/E  P/S  P/B   P/FCF  Dividend
No.                     
1   GWRE    5   5   3     3       4
2   NTCT    4   2   1     1       4
3   PEGA    3   3   4     4       3
4   BLKB    2   4   5     2       2
5   IRM     1   1   2     5       1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [rank](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) method:

```
# get columns start with P
p_cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith("P")]

# rank P columns in ascending order
df[p_cols] = df[p_cols].rank(method="dense"))

# rank Dividend column in descending order
df['Dividend'] = df.Dividend.rank(method="dense", ascending=False)
```

[image]

If you prefer a new data frame, you can use `pd.concat` to construct a new one:

```
pd.concat([df.Ticker,
           df.filter(regex="^P").rank(method="dense"),
           df.Dividend.rank(method="dense", ascending=False)], 
          axis=1)
```